Setting an array of integers in a fixture for Minitest
A Rails Ministest integration test captures a fixtures data
puts cover_recipes(:full_operator_consumer_two_parigina_promo).inspect
and returns
#<CoverRecipe id: 200929974, ... related_promo_cr_ids: [nil, nil, nil], ... updated_at: "2024-08-21 16:19:22.844416000 +0000">

The fixture is set to :
full_operator_consumer_two_parigina_promo:
[...]
  related_promo_cr_ids: [ cover_recipes(:full_operator_consumer_one_bianco_caraffa_promo).id,  
 cover_recipes(:full_operator_consumer_two_patate_fritte_promo).id,  
 cover_recipes(:full_operator_consumer_two_parigina_promo).id ]

why are these returning nil when inspected?

You already have the ids.  related_promo_cr_ids: [<%= FixtureSet.identify(:full_operator_consumer_one_bianco_caraffa_promo) %>, <%= FixtureSet.identify(:full_operator_consumer_two_patate_fritte_promo) %>, <%= FixtureSet.identify(:full_operator_consumer_two_parigina_promo) %>]

Actually needed to  identify via ActiveRecord::FixtureSet
